# what if ASCII uses 12 bits per character?

Tags: ascii, extended-ascii

If ASCII uses 7 bits to represent characters. Could someone explain what this means towards the number of  characters that are supported. How would that change if ASCII used 12 bits per character?

Comment: ASCII only defines characters 0..127, so it needs only 7 bits. If you have 12 bits, it still only needs and uses 7 bits.

Comment: ASCII is one standard. Unicode is another. Why don't you do some research on unicode to get some context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit has two possible states. A group of n bits has 2<sup>n</sup> possible states.

Therefore 7 bits can represent 2<sup>7</sup> = 128 possible characters and 12 bits can represent 2<sup>12</sup> = 4096 possible characters.

Answer (score 0):

This abridged excerpt from [Wikipedia's table of character sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_information_system_character_sets) provides historical perspective:

```
   BCDIC         1928                     6 bits  Introduced with      
                                                  the IBM card         

   FIELDATA      1956                     6/7     Battlefield          
                                          bits    information (USA)    

   EBCDIC        1963                     8 bits  IBM computers        
                                                  Teleprinters and     
                                                  computers;           

   ASCII         1963-06-17               7 bits  original             
                 (ASA X3.4-1963)                  definition of        
                                                  ASCII                

   ECMA-6        1965-04-30               7 bits  ASCII localization   

   ISO 646       1967 (ISO/R646-1967)     7 bits  ASCII localization   

                 1967 (USAS                       Close to "modern"    
   ASCII         X3.4-1967)               7 bits  definition of        
                                                  ASCII                
                                                  IBM data             

   Braille ASCII 1969                     6/7     Tactile print for    
                                          bits    blind persons        

                                                  Terminal text        
   ECMA-48       1972                     7 bits  manipulation and     
                                                  colors               

   ISO/IEC 8859  1987                     8 bits  International        
                                                  codes                

                                                  Unified encoding     
   Unicode       1991                     16/32   for most of the      
                                          bits    world's writing      
                                                  systems
```

Comment: The entry for Unicode is a bit misleading. Unicode code points go up to 0x10FFFF, which would make it 21 bits.

Comment: @melpomene, 2^21=2097152, which agrees with: *"The Unicode code space is divided into seventeen planes (the basic multilingual plane, and 16 supplementary planes), each with 65,536 (= 216) code points. Thus the total size of the Unicode code space is 17 × 65,536 = 1,114,112."* -[Code Point (WP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point)   Presumably Unicode's designers are forward looking, and they allowed some room for the standard to grow.

Answer (score 0):

A 12 bit code can support 2 to the twelve or 4096 characters, minus one or two for non-characters like null, maybe escape, and a few whitespace characters.

Now you could construct a computer with 12 bit bytes. But it would be an expensive re-engineering operation. Most computers have 8 bit bytes, at least partly because of ascii.

But the method chosen to extend ascii was Unicode, and the encoding that is emerging as standard is UTF-8 This is a superset of ascii in a sense - ascii is unicode. The unused top bit is set and additional bytes added to generate extended non-Latin characters. So it is variable width encoding, the codes are always a multiple of 8 bits, and its slightly open ended in that it is possible to add codes at the top of the range, but currently encoding never goes wider than four bytes.